# Android : phone contacts query takes long time to return the result

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm  working on Voip app ,So i have to show all contacts for user to call it .

So i used the following function :

```
public void GetContactsIntoArrayList(){
    int i = 0 ;
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    HashSet<String> tempHash = new HashSet<String >();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Person per = new Person();
        Bitmap bit_thumb ;
        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        phonenumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        contactId = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        per.setName(name);
        per.setNumber(phonenumber);
        //

        if(tempHash.add(name) ){
            i++ ;
            StoreContacts.add(per );
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText( getActivity()," "+i , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    cursor.close();
    adapter = new ContactListViewAdapter(getContext() , StoreContacts) ;
    contactsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Everything was good when my contacts count was less than 5000 contact .

But now i have 20000 contact on my phone it takes about 13 second to retrieve the result it so much .

can anyone help me to improve .

Comment: *can anyone help me to improve* ... delete 15K contacts ... but seriously ... move what you can from UI thread ... **it will not help with time** (as nothing than better hardware will not help for this iteration) but at least you will not get ANR ... you can also try to use CursorAdapter - it will remove need for iterating all elements at the start

Comment: please is there any another way to resolve it my customer will not understand this

Comment: only thing you can do is to move the code from main thread to some worker thread, so that you can avoid ANR.

Comment: Why does the customer have to understand this? The only thing (s)he would see is a loading bar e.g. Do you have the possibility to preload data while startup?

Comment: yes but it takes too 13 seconds it would be problem for me

Comment: off-topic comment: having 20k elements in ListView is pointless ...

Comment: ok please suggest a solution

Comment: i have too search bar inside the activity so every time will search it will take 13 seconds too !!

Comment: do not use `ContactListViewAdapter` - use `SimpleCursorAdapter` instead

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/c6182418fd1c387bf5b6 uncomment/comment right code to get contacts instead smses

Comment: i will see then i will reply you

Comment: thank you guys by the way i didn't have to remove the 15,000 contact like what @Selvin suggest

Comment: @pskink depends if we want to build good app or just app which works ... good app should not have IO operation on main thread :) ... also without loader ListView will not refresh if there will be new contact after background sync :)

Comment: :) no ... I've just check my biggest project ... no single setImageResource ... but ... yeah, got one decodeByteArray on main thread  - only because 1. I'm lazy. 2. have no time to fix it

Comment: no ... but setting android:backround (other drawable) should count, too - and i have such calls  :) ... it's getting off-topic, but you cannot compare setting small drawable from xml layout(which would be really pain in the ass to do it asynchronously for every single drawable in the project) with something that you have almost out of box .... *then use it: like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/1MQAY4vq)* where you are closing cursor? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by separate the cursor variables initialization

It was look like this :

```
cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null,  ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

And I replace it with following code  :

```
    String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
    String orderBy = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

    cursor =  getActivity().getContentResolver().query( uri, projection, null, null, orderBy) ;
```

And now its works 20,000 contact takes 1 second

Comment: thank you so much for providing this but i think what i made its enough for my situation now  – @pskink

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you've 100,000 contacts in your phone and it takes one minute for the cursor to load, and this much loading time is irritating in respect to user.
One solution is to fetch contacts using a limit, like

> SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 0,30

and then populate the listview(RecyclerView).
This way is much meaningful than fetching

> SELECT * FROM TABLE

because we can't show 100,000 contacts at the same time,
while the user starts scrolling and reaches the bottom of first limit of elements, fetch the next limit of contacts and update the listview.

Since in our case we are not dealing with SQL Tables ,
To set limit in ContentProvider;

```
Cursor c = resolver.query(
    MyTable.CONTENT_URI,
    MyTable.PROJECTION,
    null,
    null,
    " limit 1 offset 2");
```